# Check file exist or not using PHP grid

Tags: javascript, php, jqgrid, file-exists, phpgrid

I am using [PHPGrid](https://phpgrid.com/example/display-dynamic-url/#prettyPhoto) for creating dashboard in which it will display all product details (product Name,productiimage,json file created for product).

If json file already created for product then it will display edit option else create file option.I save json file in a folder(local system).

My question is if I delete json file from folder it should display create json file option but now it is showing edit option( because it  read json file value  only from database). It should also check the file value(comes from database ) is exist in folder or not.

In php grid Hot to do this ?

**UPDATE:**

```
<?php       $dg = new C_DataGrid("SELECT * FROM product where  usercreated='$uid'");
                $dg -> set_col_title("user", "username");
                $dg -> set_col_hidden("jsonfile");
                $dg -> enable_export('HTML');
                $dg -> set_col_title("id" ,'pid');
                $dg -> set_dimension(1000, 412); 

                $col_formatter = <<<COLFORMATTER
                function(cellvalue, options, rowObject){
                var id =rowObject[0];
                var jsin =rowObject[5];

                if (jsin!=''){
                    return '<a href="editadpage.php?id='+ id +'"><input type="submit" class="edit1" title="Edit"  style="font-size:11px; font-weight:bold;"></a>';
                }else{
                   return '<a class="notactive" href="editadpage.php?id='+ id +'"><input type="submit" class="greycreate " title="Edit"  style="font-size:11px; font-weight:bold;"></a>';
                }

                }

    ?>
```

Comment: [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) may solve your problem?

Comment: is_readable() would be better, this accounts for any issues with access to a file that may be on the server, but not readable (cmod levels).

Comment: @natanel97  I added code .In this edit like is create in javascript code.How to check file exist or not in javascript.(Files are in local system Not on server)

Comment: You should also use filter function set_query_filter. Do not hard code in the query. https://phpgrid.com/documentation/set_query_filterwhere/